# Leer xml o json con jquery

Tags: json, soap

Siempre trabajo con jquery y php mediante JSON pero Estoy trabajando con un servicio SOAP de AFIP que devuelve datos supongo en JSON, pero el caso es que intente de esta forma leer la respuesta:

```html
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/afip/consultaPadron.php",
            data: {"CUIT":CUIT}, 
     dataType:'json',
  
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
               
            },
            
            success: function(cli){
                console.log(cli);
                 $.each(cli, function(i,item){
                       
    datosgrales=cli[i].datosGenerales;
             datosRegimen=cli[i].datosRegimenGeneral;
            
            
 });
                $.each(datosgrales,function(i,item)
                {
                 persona=datosgrales.tipoPersona;
                 apellido= datosgrales.apellido;
             
                 nombre= datosgrales.nombre;  
                  razonsocial = apellido + ' '+ nombre;
                 
                  domicilio=datosgrales.domicilioFiscal;
                 });
                  
                 $.each(domicilio,function(i,item)
                 {
                  direccion = domicilio.direccion + ' '+ domicilio.localidad +' ' +domicilio.descripcionProvincia;
                 
                 }
                 );
                $.each(datosRegimen,function(i,item)
                {
                 personai=datosRegimen.impuesto;
           
                 });
                  $.each(personai,function(i,item)
                {
                 condicion=personai[i].idImpuesto;
               if (condicion===30){
                $("#iva").val("Responsable Inscripto");
               }
                 });
 
                alert(razonsocial); 
                 $("#Nombre").val(razonsocial);
                $("#domicilio").val(direccion);  
                $("#persona").val(persona);
```

Para lo mismo en [php](/questions/tagged/php) hago:

```
$resultado = $padron->getPersona(
  array(
    'token' => $TA->credentials->token,
    'sign' => $TA->credentials->sign,
    'cuitRepresentada' => 20111111118, // es el cuit con el que pedi el certificao
    'idPersona' =>$CUITI,
  )
);

var_dump($resultado);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Osea yo lo estoy devolviendo como un JSON pero el `var_dump` de resultado, es decir la respuesta directa es:

```
["personaReturn"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
    ["datosGenerales"]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (8) {
      ["apellido"]=>
      string(6) "ANSWER"
      ["domicilioFiscal"]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (6) {
        ["codPostal"]=>
        string(4) "1111"
        ["descripcionProvincia"]=>
        string(10) "ENTRE RIOS"
        ["direccion"]=>
        string(27) "9999 MTS. AL ESTE ESCUELA 90"
        ["idProvincia"]=>
        int(5)
        ["localidad"]=>
        string(22) "COLONIA LA COLONITA"
        ["tipoDomicilio"]=>
        string(6) "FISCAL"
      }
      ["estadoClave"]=>
      string(6) "ACTIVO"
      ["idPersona"]=>
      float(20111111110)
      ["mesCierre"]=>
      int(12)
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(7) "PEDRO"
      ["tipoClave"]=>
      string(4) "CUIT"
      ["tipoPersona"]=>
      string(6) "FISICA"
    }
```

Aparentemente es un json sino me equivoco, pero, ¿cómo lo leo? Actualmente obtengo:

> Error en la peticion AJAX.. Requested JSON parse failed.

Es como que no llega un JSON bien formado; de hecho probe un `alert` en el success y nada. ¿Es JSON o no lo que devuelve el servicio?

Haciendo:

```html
var_dump($resultado);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Recibo:

```
2019-01-18 10:11:202019-01-18 17:48:04object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
  ["personaReturn"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
    ["datosGenerales"]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (8) {
      ["apellido"]=>
      string(6) "ANSWER"
      ["domicilioFiscal"]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (6) {
        ["codPostal"]=>
        string(4) "3228"
        ["descripcionProvincia"]=>
        string(10) "ENTRE RIOS"
        ["direccion"]=>
        string(27) "999 MTS. AL ESTE ESCUELA 90"
        ["idProvincia"]=>
        int(5)
        ["localidad"]=>
        string(22) "COLONIA LA COLONITA"
        ["tipoDomicilio"]=>
        string(6) "FISCAL"
      }
      ["estadoClave"]=>
      string(6) "ACTIVO"
      ["idPersona"]=>
      float(20111111110)
      ["mesCierre"]=>
      int(12)
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(7) "PEDRO"
      ["tipoClave"]=>
      string(4) "CUIT"
      ["tipoPersona"]=>
      string(6) "FISICA"
    }
    ["datosRegimenGeneral"]=>
    object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
      ["actividad"]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (5) {
        ["descripcionActividad"]=>
        string(27) "CULTIVO DE FRUTAS CÍTRICAS"
        ["idActividad"]=>
        int(11110)
        ["nomenclador"]=>
        int(883)
        ["orden"]=>
        int(1)
        ["periodo"]=>
        int(201311)
      }
      ["categoriaAutonomo"]=>
      object(stdClass)#13 (4) {
        ["descripcionCategoria"]=>
        string(32) "T3 CAT II INGRESOS DESDE $1"
        ["idCategoria"]=>
        int(302)
        ["idImpuesto"]=>
        int(308)
        ["periodo"]=>
        int(200703)
      }
      ["impuesto"]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#14 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(26) "GANANCIAS PERSONAS FISICAS"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(11)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200407)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(3) "IVA"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200407)
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#16 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(29) "EMPLEADOR-APORTES SEG. SOCIAL"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(301)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200806)
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
          ["descripcionImpuesto"]=>
          string(28) "APORTES SEG.SOCIAL AUTONOMOS"
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(308)
          ["periodo"]=>
          int(200407)
        }
      }
    }
    ["metadata"]=>
    object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
      ["fechaHora"]=>
      string(29) "2019-01-18T10:11:21.649-03:00"
      ["servidor"]=>
      string(19) "dominioXXX.afip.gov.ar"
    }
  }
}
```

Que se traduce a:

```
{
    "personaReturn":{
        "datosGenerales":{
            "apellido":"ANSWER",
            "domicilioFiscal":{
                "codPostal":"1111",
                "descripcionProvincia":"ENTRE RIOS",
                "direccion":"9999 MTS. AL ESTE ESCUELA 90",
                "idProvincia":5,
                "localidad":"COLONIA LA COLONITA",
                "tipoDomicilio":"FISCAL"
            },
            "estadoClave":"ACTIVO",
            "idPersona":20111111110,
            "mesCierre":12,
            "nombre":"PEDRO",
            "tipoClave":"CUIT",
            "tipoPersona":"FISICA"
        },
        "datosRegimenGeneral":{
            "actividad":{
                "descripcionActividad":"CULTIVO DE FRUTAS C\u00cdTRICAS",
                "idActividad":12200,
                "nomenclador":883,
                "orden":1,
                "periodo":201311
            },
            "categoriaAutonomo":{
                "descripcionCategoria":"T3 CAT II INGRESOS DESDE $1",
                "idCategoria":302,
                "idImpuesto":308,
                "periodo":200703
            },
            "impuesto":[
                {
                    "descripcionImpuesto":"GANANCIAS PERSONAS FISICAS",
                    "idImpuesto":11,
                    "periodo":200407
                },
                {
                    "descripcionImpuesto":"IVA",
                    "idImpuesto":30,
                    "periodo":200407
                },
                {
                    "descripcionImpuesto":"EMPLEADOR-APORTES SEG. SOCIAL",
                    "idImpuesto":301,
                    "periodo":200806
                },
                {
                    "descripcionImpuesto":"APORTES SEG.SOCIAL AUTONOMOS",
                    "idImpuesto":308,
                    "periodo":200407
                }
            ]
        },
        "metadata":{
            "fechaHora":"2019-01-18T10:11:21.649-03:00",
            "servidor":"dominioXX.afip.gov.ar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aumm te llega un array que dentro tiene un object o sea una clase no te llega un json, si fuese json verias algo como {"personaReturn":{"datosGenerales":{"apellido":"ANSWER"}}}

Comment: Y como puedo pasar ese array a JSON o trabajarlo con JQUERY..porque quiero cargar los datos del cliente buscado por CUIT por ej

Comment: Lo raro es que el encode debería poder pasar ese array a un json... no te da más información el error?

Comment: El AJAX devuelve error en la peticion ajax. requested json parse failed..ni siquiera entra en el success.

Comment: Claro porque le dices que es un json lo que va a recibir e intentar serializarlo, me refería al código en php, por otra parte puedes revisar en herramientas de desarrollador->pestaña network  y ves la petición para que veas cómo es la respuesta y la colocas acá.

Comment: Lo que esta en negrita en la pregunta es lo que devuelve en php..es la variable resultado.

Comment: Así lo interpreta el php, me gustaría ver la respuesta en bruto de la petición como llega al navegador

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta..como veras tenes razon esta la respuesta del servidor y un JSON osea que lo interpreta bien

Comment: si intentas esto json_encode($resultado->personaReturn) o por si me estoy equivocando de tipo de dato json_encode($resultado['personaReturn'])

Comment: Ya resolvi..y si es viable lo que dices..tenia esas fechas antes del corchete que eran dos echo innecesarios..ahora funciona

Comment: ah! eso lo pusiste tu? pensaba que venia del servicio de afip por eso te dije que accedieras directo a la variable... bueno bien! otra cosa, edita la pregunta y coloca data dummy en cada parte de la respuesta de la petición donde está información sensible. Pobre WOLFRAM tiene toda su vida en stackoverflow xD.

Comment: wolfram no existe..los valores devueltos por afip en homologacion no son reales